# I'm trying to incorporate scenes into my mini space shooter game but Private Method Error keeps occuring

Tags: ruby, libgosu

Whenever the game reaches  the draw_end method it crashes. The draw_start and  draw_game methods work great but the game crashes when it reaches the draw_end and therefore the ending credits cannot be displayed. The error is are these :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    9: from sector_five_scenes.rb:275:in `<main>'
    8: from /Users/skynet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu/patches.rb:72:in `tick'
    7: from /Users/skynet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu/patches.rb:72:in `tick'
    6: from sector_five_scenes.rb:29:in `draw'
    5: from sector_five_scenes.rb:237:in `draw_end'
    4: from /Users/skynet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu/compat.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Window>'
    3: from /Users/skynet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5/lib/gosu/compat.rb:165:in `clip_to'
    2: from sector_five_scenes.rb:238:in `block in draw_end'
    1: from sector_five_scenes.rb:238:in `each'
sector_five_scenes.rb:239:in `block (2 levels) in draw_end': private method `draw' called for #<Credit:0x00007ff1b48ad448> (NoMethodError)


I have tried renaming the methods in the credits file. I have tried adding  and removing the require_relative 'credit'. I removed the @credits array from the initialize_end method and  placed  it into the initialize method 

Aside from that I'm really out of ideas of where to go from here  and would really appreciate your help.
```

## This  portion connects all the classes to the  main file

```
 require 'gosu'
 require_relative 'credit'
 require_relative 'player'
 require_relative 'enemy'
 require_relative 'bullet'
 require_relative 'explosion'
```

This part opens the window and sets the first  scene.

```
 class SectorFive < Gosu::Window
   WIDTH =  800
   HEIGHT = 600
   ENEMY_FREQUENCY = 0.05
   MAX_ENEMIES = 100
   def initialize
     super(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
     self.caption =  "Sector Five"
     @background_image = Gosu::Image.new('ima/start.png')
     @scene = :start
   end

#The draw method below is  the guide for this program.

 def  draw
   case @scene
  when:start
    draw_start
  when:game
    draw_game
  when:end
    draw_end
  end
end
```

This sets the background image
    def draw_start
      @background_image.draw(0,0,0)
    end

This draws all the enemy, player, bullets, and explosions

```
def draw_game
    @player.draw
    @background_image.draw(0,0,0)

    @enemies.each  do |enemy|
          enemy.draw
    end
    @enemybullets.each do |bullet|
          bullet.draw
    end
    @bullets.each do |bullet|
      bullet.draw_two
    end
    @explosions.each do |explosion|
      explosion.draw
    end
    @playerexplosions.each do |explosion|
      explosion.draw_two
    end
 end
```

## This allows the game to update every frame

```
 def update
   case @scene
   when :game
     update_game
  when :end
     update_end
   end
 end
```

This executes the start of the game after the first scene

```
 def button_down(id)
   case @scene
  when :start
    button_down_start(id)
  when :game
    button_down_game(id)
  when :end
    button_down_end(id)
  end
end
```

This method  calls the initialize_game method

```
def button_down_start(id)
  initialize_game
end
```

This method defines the initialize_game method by defining the variables
    def initialize_game
        @background_image = Gosu::Image.new('ima/space.png')
        @player = Player.new(self)
        @enemies = []
        @bullets = []
        @enemybullets = []
        @random_enemy_bullets = []
        @explosions = []
        @playerexplosions = []
        @framecounter = 0
        @scene = :game
        @enemies_appeared = 0
        @enemies_destroyed = 0
        @credits = []
      end

This is what allows the game to function. It tells the game what to do!

```
def update_game
  @framecounter += 1
@player.turn_left if button_down?(Gosu::KbLeft)
@player.turn_right if  button_down?(Gosu::KbRight)
@player.accelerate if button_down?(Gosu::KbUp)
@player.backward if  button_down?(Gosu::KbDown)
@player.move
   if rand < ENEMY_FREQUENCY
      @enemies.push Enemy.new(self)
      @enemies_appeared += 1
   end
   @enemies.each do |enemy|
      enemy.move
    end
    #Fires a bullet
    @enemies.select do |enemy|
      if @framecounter % 600 == 0
        @enemybullets.push Bullet.new(self, @enemies[-1].x, @enemies[-1].y, @enemies[-1].angle)
        if @enemies.length >  3
          @enemybullets.push Bullet.new(self, enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.angle)
        end
      end
   end
# Detects whether there is a collision between a player bullet and an  enemy.
   @enemies.dup.each do |enemy|
     @bullets.dup.each do  |bullet|
       distance = Gosu.distance(enemy.x, enemy.y, bullet.x, bullet.y)
       if distance < enemy.radius + bullet.radius
         @enemies.delete enemy
         @bullets.delete bullet
         @explosions.push Explosion.new(self, enemy.x, enemy.y)
         @enemies_destroyed += 1
       end
     end
   end
   @explosions.dup.each do |explosion|
    if @explosions.length > 15
     @explosions.delete explosion
     @explosions.delete explosion
   end
end
    @explosions.dup.each do |explosion|
      @enemies.dup.each do |enemy|
        distance = Gosu.distance(explosion.x, explosion.y, enemy.x, enemy.y)
        if distance  < explosion.radius + enemy.radius
          @enemies.delete enemy
          @explosions.push Explosion.new(self, enemy.x, enemy.y)
          @enemies_destroyed += 1
        end
      end
    end

#Explosions on the player
@enemybullets.each  do |bullet|
  distance = Gosu.distance(bullet.x, bullet.y, @player.x, @player.y)
  if distance < bullet.radius + @player.radius
    @enemybullets.delete bullet
    @playerexplosions.push Explosion.new(self, @player.x, @player.y)
  end
end
@playerexplosions.dup.each do |explosion|
  @explosions.delete explosion unless explosion.finishedtwo
end

@playerexplosions.dup.each do |explosion|
  @enemies.dup.each do |enemy|
    distance = Gosu.distance(explosion.x, explosion.y, enemy.x, enemy.y)
    if distance < explosion.radius + enemy.radius
      @enemies.delete enemy
      @playerexplosions.delete explosion
      @explosions.push Explosion.new(self, enemy.x, enemy.y)
    end
  end
end
   @enemies.dup.each do |enemy|
     if enemy.y > HEIGHT + enemy.radius
       @enemies.delete enemy
     end
   end
   @bullets.dup.each do |bullet|
     @bullets.delete bullet unless bullet.onscreen?
   end
   @enemybullets.each do |bullet|
     bullet.enemy_move
   end
   @bullets.each do |bullet|
     bullet.move
   end
   @explosions.each  do |explosion|
     explosion.move
   end
    @playerexplosions.each do |explosion|
      explosion.move
    end
```

This part of the update method defines when the game ends.

```
    initialize_end(:count_reached) if @enemies_appeared > MAX_ENEMIES
    @enemies.each do |enemy|
      distance = Gosu::distance(enemy.x, enemy.y, @player.x, @player.y)
    initialize_end(:hit_by_enemy) if distance < @player.radius + enemy.radius
    end
    initialize_end(:off_top) if @player.y < -@player.radius
  end
```

## This method allows the player to fire bullets

```
def button_down_game(id)
  if  id == Gosu::KbSpace
    @bullets.push Bullet.new(self, @player.x, @player.y, @player.angle)
  end
end
```

This method sets the end scene("The scene that is  not working") and displays messages on the bottom of the screen and top of the screen depending on the  players fate and also is suppose to display the ending credits in the center of the  screen produced by the credits.txt file. The credits should slowly move -y out of the  window.

```
def initialize_end(fate)
  case fate
  when :count_reached
    @message = "You Made it! You destroyed #{@enemies_destroyed} ships"
    @message2 = "and #{100 - @enemies_destroyed} reached the base."

  when :hit_by_enemy
    @message = "You were struck by an enemy ship"
    @message2 = "Before your ship was destroyed, "
    @message2 += "you took out #{@enemies_destroyed} enemy ships!"

  when :off_top
    @message = "You got too close to the enemy mothership."
    @message2 = "Before your ship was destroyed, "
    @message2 += "you took out #{@enemies_destroyed} enemy ships!"
  end
  @bottom_message = "Press P to play again, or Q to quit."
  @message_font = Gosu::Font.new(28)
  y = 700
  File.open('credits.txt').each do |line|
    @credits.push(Credit.new(self,line.chomp,100,y))
    y+=30
 end
 @scene = :end
end
```

This is  the method that is producing the Private Method error.  I can't figure  out why.

```
def draw_end
   clip_to(50,140,700,360) do
  @credits.each do |credit|
    credit.draw
  end
 end
draw_line(0,140,Gosu::Color::RED,WIDTH,140,Gosu::Color::RED)
@message_font.draw(@message,40,40,1,1,1,Gosu::Color::FUCHSIA)
@message_font.draw(@message2,40,75,1,1,1,Gosu::Color::FUCHSIA)
draw_line(0,500,Gosu::Color::RED,WIDTH,500,Gosu::Color::RED)
@message_font.draw(@bottom_message,180,540,1,1,1,Gosu::Color::AQUA)
end
```

The methods below do not work either. Produces the same Private method  error. I don't understand why this doesn't  work because I have used require_relative on the credit ruby file.

```
def update_end
  @credits.each do |credit|
    credit.move
  end
  if @credits.last.y < 150
    @credits.each do |credit|
      credit.reset
    end
  end
end
```

# This method gives the player the option to play again  or quit  the  game and  the player will select the button based on his or her preference. 
    def button_down_end(id)
       if id == Gosu::KbP
          initialize_game
        elsif id  == Gosu::KbQ
          close
        end
      end

```
end

window = SectorFive.new
window.show


----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

"This is the  Credit class"

class Credit
      SPEED = 1
      attr_reader :y, :x, :text

```
  def initialize(window,text, x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = @initial_y =  y
    @text = text
    @font = Gosu::Font.new(24)
  end
end


  def move
    @y -= SPEED
  end

  def draw
    @font.draw(@text, @x, @y, 1)
  end

  def reset
    @y = @initial_y
  end

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
"""The credits.txt file"""
```

"This is a part of the File.open method used to push the line into the credits array."

```
SectorFive 

By: John Jordan Shelley 

Based on a Tutorial from 

Learn Game Programming with Ruby 
By Mark Sobkowicz

—Images——
Game art from OpenGameArt.org
Licensed under Creative Commons: Domain CC0

The game should smoothly execute the initialize end method and give the player options depending on the player's fate and play the ending credits.
```

Comment: Your credit class looks incomplete but from what I see there's two end in "def initialize(window,text, x, y)" which closes the class context thus define the move, draw and reset methods in a global private context. (All method defined outside a class are private when loaded through require "script".)

Comment: Thank You very much